# Nextjs 13. When using Parallel Routes, error.tsx and loading.tsx does not work

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I started working with Nextjs new feature Parallel Routes.

My app structure looks like this:

```
[course]
├── @children
├── @hero
|   ├── page.tsx
|   ├── loading.tsx
|   └── error.tsx
└── layout.tsx
```

I see @children and @hero slots, but **loading** and **error** doesn't works.

I tried to add async fetch to `[course]/@hero/page.tsx`, and instead of showing the loading state from `[course]/@hero/loading.tsx` it just ignores it and I can't even see other slots (@children) until it finishes fetching.

Idk, maybe I am missing something very important.
Please, help!

Comment: Each page still need to have a `loading` component, in your structure it seems like you don't have it for @children?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Danila. What about parent pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create route group inside parallel slot

```
├── @hero
|   ├── (hack)
|   |   └── page.tsx
|   ├── loading.tsx
|   └── error.tsx
└── layout.tsx
```